# converter minutos em : horas e minutos

Tags: php, time

Tenho `150 minutos`; como converter isso para ficar `2h30min`?
Por exemplo, consegui fazer uma conversão usando o código abaixo, mas ele retornar `2.55` onde ta o erro ?

```
$minutos = 150;

if($minutos > 60){
    $exibe2 = $minutos / 60;
    $exibe = $exibe2 . "min"; 
}else{
    $exibe = "0:" . $minutos;
}
$hora_final = $exibe;
```

Comment: nesse exemplo que vc mandou, aconteceu oque eu citei aqui @Sam

Answer (score 1):

Você está fazendo uma divisão decimal e o PHP está retornando corretamente.
O que você devia fazer é usar as horas apenas a parte inteira e fazer a operação de resto pra pegar os minutos:

```
$horas = (int) $minutos / 60;
$min = $minutos % 60; 
$exibe = "{$horas}h{$min}min";
```

Comment: vlw galera deu certo aqui

Answer (score 1):

```
$minutos = 150;

$horas = floor($minutos / 60);
$minutos = $minutos % 60;
$exibe = $horas."h ".$minutos."m";
$hora_final = $exibe;
```